# Point of Sale Application Receipt Printing

Tags: c#, point-of-sale

I am working on a small project for a Retail Management Software, which will be using a POS printer (I think that's what we call it). I need a create a bill for it in the end. But i am stuck here, and not able to proceed.  So suppose if I generate my bill in a separate form with appropriate dimensions (of width of POS bills), will i be able to print it properly?
I am using C# and .NET 4.0 framework. I don't have much knowledge about POS devices. I am working for really a small local client which needs a basic model of software. I am also a fresher so please help me out.

If my question is not clear, let me know i will try to elaborate my thought.

Comment: Just so you know, POS == Point Of Sale

Comment: This is a rather large issue, and creating a printable receipt through a POS printer is no small feat. You should probably search around Google first, since StackOverflow is for specific programming quesitons.

Comment: @jadarnel27: you can say that, i just know this and have some idea about WEPOS

Comment: First task should be to get the manual for the POS device, from my limited contact with Receipt printers is that you generally have to dive into the bowels of the system to print properly.  Unfortunately it's not like printing on an A4 piece of paper.

Comment: @user815600, i think it would be easier to print, if you output the bill in console application format (i mean in command prompt window), and try to print from there. you will need your client's printer for demo prints and then fix a format for the bills generated hereafter, but that is just my opinion :)

Comment: I will  be finishing the POS device manual tonight itself and will see what can be done in Console. Do printers of different brands(Companies) behave differently? Do WEPOS has to do anything with printing POS receipts?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but for those still looking for a solution, I can tell you what I did.

After spending many hours messing with OPOS and POS for .Net, I ended up just abandoning those and just using the built-in System.Drawing.Printing libraries. The OPOS and POS for .Net ended up being a pain to get working and ultimately didn't work as well as the built-in libraries.

I'm using an Epson TM-T20II receipt printer.

Here's some code that worked well for me.

```
public static void PrintReceiptForTransaction()
    {

        PrintDocument recordDoc = new PrintDocument();

        recordDoc.DocumentName = "Customer Receipt";
        recordDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ReceiptPrinter.PrintReceiptPage); // function below
        recordDoc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController(); // hides status dialog popup
        // Comment if debugging 
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        ps.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T20II Receipt";
        recordDoc.PrinterSettings = ps;
        recordDoc.Print();
        // --------------------------------------

        // Uncomment if debugging - shows dialog instead
        //PrintPreviewDialog printPrvDlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        //printPrvDlg.Document = recordDoc;
        //printPrvDlg.Width = 1200;
        //printPrvDlg.Height = 800;
        //printPrvDlg.ShowDialog();
        // --------------------------------------

        recordDoc.Dispose();

    }


private static void PrintReceiptPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        float x = 10;
        float y = 5;
        float width = 270.0F; // max width I found through trial and error
        float height = 0F;

        Font drawFontArial12Bold = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
        Font drawFontArial10Regular = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        // Set format of string.
        StringFormat drawFormatCenter = new StringFormat();
        drawFormatCenter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        StringFormat drawFormatLeft = new StringFormat();
        drawFormatLeft.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        StringFormat drawFormatRight = new StringFormat();
        drawFormatRight.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;

        // Draw string to screen.
        string text = "Company Name";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, drawFontArial12Bold, drawBrush, new RectangleF(x, y, width, height), drawFormatCenter);
        y += e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, drawFontArial12Bold).Height;

        text = "Address";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, drawFontArial10Regular, drawBrush, new RectangleF(x, y, width, height), drawFormatCenter);
        y += e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, drawFontArial10Regular).Height;

        // ... and so on

 }
```

Hopefully it helps someone skip all the messing around with custom drivers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I designed a POS application (in Delphi) and altough there are many little issues with printing a receipt or a bill it´s not rocket science. I just print a receipt by simply, well, printing like any other printer, the difference is that you send lines of 30-38 characters long (depending on the printer driver, font and size). To start, you could print using 2 methods: Sending Ascii characters and sending printer commands (to set the font style, color, etc) for that specific printer or the second method is to set the font, size, etc using C# like printing to any other normal/desktop printer.

You could try printing following the example of the page and my suggestions:
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/06/24/printing.html

Comment: nice to have your reply Luis. Let me go through it. will comment if every thing DOES NOT go according to plan